# C# Format double limiting significant digits but restrict scientific notation

Tags: c#, number-formatting

I want to format my `double` values limiting to 2 significant places, but not in integer part of the number.

Currently I use `G2` notation, but it displays number in scientific notation if integer part contains more than 2 places.

Also I tried `0.##`, but it keeps 2 significant places in the fractional part no matter how many are there in the integer one.

What I want is this:

```
1234     => 1234
123.4    => 123
12.34    => 12
1.234    => 1.2
0.1234   => 0.12
0.01234  => 0.012
0.001234 => 0.0012
```

Is it any standard way to do it or should I reinvent the wheel myself?

Comment: I don't understand the logic here. Why 12.34 becomes 12, while 1.234 becomes 1.2?

Comment: The logic is simple: I don't need more then 2 significant place precision, but I want to avoid scientific notation. 12.34 do have 2 places in the integer part, so I don't need the fractional one. 1.234 doesn't, so I need one place of the fractional part.

Comment: So... you need at least two digits that are larger than 0 (based on your last edit)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Is there a specific scientific or standardized name to this type of formatting?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It's just my wish.

Comment: Please add sample for 0.01234, 0.001234

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out  a way to do it, as it's a bit unconventional, but this extension may work:

```
public static string DoubleLimited(this double n){      
    return n < 100 ? $"{n:G2}" : n.ToString("#0.");
}
```

used like

```
var num = 1234.0;
Console.WriteLine(num.DoubleLimited());
```

Comment: I wanted to make it using custom format specifier (so it could be used it in, for example, WPF format specifiers), but it seems impossible. Your solution works perfectly.